# How to get impersonated UserGuid Id in docusign

Tags: rest, docusignapi

I am trying to get the impersonated userguid from the docusign api. Per the documentation I need to call /restapi/v2/accounts/account_id/users?email=email, which is not working for me. I assume the full url would be `https://admin.docusign.com/restapi/v2/accounts/account_id/users?email="sampleemail@gmail.com"` . 
I am getting a 404 when entering my email in the above format.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have the incorrect domain. API Calls generally don't get made against `admin.docusign.com`. You'll want to make that call against the Application Server your account is on.

In the Sandbox environment that will be `demo.docusign.net`. In prod you'd need to make a [UserInfo](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/user-info-endpoints) call to determine which server your account is on. It could be something like `www.docusign.net` or `na2.docusign.net`, but there are several possible domains.

Comment: I tried https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/account_id/users?email="xx@gmail.com" and got an error - The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified.

Comment: to be clear, you are replacing the {{account_id}} portion of the URL with your actual account ID, correct? Have you completed one of the authentication workflows to get a valid auth token?

Comment: Ok thanks, no I was not. I tried with that as well but was unsuccessful. I found the impersonatedUserId in the user information within the admin section. The documentation is pretty unclear.

Comment: If you're still having trouble, I'd recommend opening a new question with specifics about what's getting stuck now.

Comment: I am not having trouble finding the impersonated user guid. I am having trouble accessing that api.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get Impersonate GUID ,

1. Login to admin account
2. Under setting options Click API and keys
3. Value under the user id text  box is Impersonate GUID
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

During configuration & setup:
 1. You have an account admin enter information such as account, their userId ("API User Name" in web app). Save both items.
 
 2. You follow the "consent flow", get their consent, generate a JWT and
    exchange for a token.
 3. Use the /user_info call against the account
    server to get the list of their accounts.  If more than one account
    in the array, find the one that matches what they entered in the
    configuration.  Get and save the associated "base_uri".  You will
    use that for all subsequent API calls.
 
Your application now has stored the account ID, the admin's "userId", and the base URI to built API URLs.

During business application operations:
Admin is "Bob".  Sender is "Jill"
You need to get an access token for Jill.
 1.  Create JWT for Bob, exchange for access token, make GET /users?email={Jill's email).  This gives you Jill's "userId".
 2. Create JWT for Jill, exchange for access token.
 3. Make API call as Jill, using her access token.